# Mesaure upload and download speed in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, network-programming, network-protocols

I would like to measure the upload and download speed of data in iPhone, is any API available to achieve the same? Is it correct to measure it on the basis of dividing total bytes received with time taken in  response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it *is* correct to measure the total bytes / time taken, that is exactly what the speed is. You might want to take an average if you want to constantly show the download speed.., like using 500 bytes and the time it took to download those particular ones.

For doing this you could like have an NSMutableArray, as a buffer, which you empty idk every 2 seconds. Then you do [bufferMutableArray length]/2 and you know how many bytes a second you had those 2 seconds. When you empty the buffer ofc append to the data you are downloading.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API to know the speed.

Total data received/sent and time only will give you average speed. There use to be lot of variation in the speed over the time so if you want more accurate value then do the speed calculation based on sampling.

(Data transferred in 1 miniut) /(60 seconds) ---> this solution only if you need greater accuracy in the speed calculation. The sampling duration can changed based on the level of accuracy required.